# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception: the parameter number 1 is not valid

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Using JDBC SQL driver, I receive the following error:

> `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception: the parameter number
>   1 is not valid.`

The relevant code is as follows:

```
CallableStatement preparedCall;
String sql = "{call [dbo].[my_sproc] (?) }";
preparedCall = conn.prepareCall(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

DBLookup.setObject(preparedCall, 1, "Some value");

ParameterMetaData pmd = ps.getParameterMetaData();
int parameterType = pmd.getParameterType(1); //<-- here is where it's thrown
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the connecting user credentials not having appropriate access to the stored procedure in SQL Server.

Grant EXECUTE permissions and this should be resolved.